# SASS to watch over whole root

Tags: ubuntu, sass

I'm attempting to use SASS on a development server I have at home.

I'm trying to find a way to have SASS by default watching all the different sites (folders inside the web root). I wouldn't like if I had to manually set SASS to watch over each and every site and everytime I created a new site.

Basically, it would need to find every .scss/.sass modified inside the root and create a .css at the same location.

All I could find is the basic `sass --watch origin:destination` but it's not what I need, since all my SASS files would be in different folders.

Just in case, I'm running an Ubuntu server and I do have ruby+sass already installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

...Duh.

The obvious way is the correct way. 
The basic `sass --watch origin:destination` is recursive and does watch subfolders.

I feel dumb.

Comment: Not sure now... but 3 years ago it was.

Comment: It works as expected if your .scss files are not named as partials (file name beginning with underscore). Partials need to be further compiled using some other build tool I guess.

Comment: Keep in mind that this question/answer is almost 5 years old. If this is not the correct to do it now, you can edit the answer or send a new one, I guess...